# Select only those elements which has changed there positions after sorting by .sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have 5 divs . They are ordered as per priority.I am sorting there positions by using jquery sortable. Is there any way to know the position of only those divs which has changed there position during sorting.

HTML Section:

```
<body>

  <div id="sortable">
    <?php foreach($data as $row){ ?>
    <div class="alert alert-success" data-id="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" role="alert"><?php echo $row['div-name']; ?></div>
    <?php } ?>
  </div>

</body>


Sctript part:

<script>
  $( function() {
    var lastMoved = null;
    $("#sortable div").mousedown(function(){
        lastMoved = this;
    });
    $("#sortable").sortable({
      start: function(e, ui) {
        //alert("");
        // console.log("Prev: "+$(this).attr('data-id'));
      },
      update: function(event, ui) {
        alert("Moving: "+$(lastMoved).attr("data-id"));
        alert("Moved to: "+parseInt($(lastMoved).index()+1));
      },
      stop: function(event, ui) {
        var data = "";

        $("#sortable div").each(function(i, el){
            var p = $(el).attr("data-id").toLowerCase().replace(" ", "_");
            data += p+"="+parseInt($(el).index()+1)+",";
        });
        console.log(data.slice(0, -1));

    }
    });
  } );
  </script>
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried? Add some jquery, html code

Comment: To answer your question: there certainly is a way. What have you tried?

Comment: Well the elements that have changed their position are obviously the ones that are not at the same position they where before any more ...

Comment: How can I get those elements? Supppose I have changes div no 5 to div no 1 then these two div5 is priority 1 and div 1 is priority 2 div 2 is priority 3, div 3  is priority 4 div 4 is priority 5 . How can I console these changing div ids.